# MGTwitterEngine with update_with_media

Tags: twitter, oauth, mgtwitterengine

Wondering if anyone has found a MGTwitterEngine that has implemented update_with_media? I am using it with OAuth / SAOAuthTwitterEngine

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on it but having a lot of problems.  Check http://github.com/rmd6502/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone